# How to assert block of a mock in mocha

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, ruby-mocha

*This example is contrived, please don't take it verbatim as my code.*

I have the need to assert something like the following:

```
def mymethod
    Dir.chdir('/tmp') do
        `ls`
    end
end
```

In the end I want to assert that:

1. Dir.chdir is invoked with the appropriate parameters.
2. ` is invoked with the appropriate parameters

I started off with...

```
Dir.expects(:chdir).with('/tmp')
```

but after that I'm not sure how to invoke the block passed to Dir.chdir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the mocha [yields](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#yields-instance_method) method. Also, writing an expectation for the *backtick* method is rather interesting. You need to make an expectation like this:

```
expects("`")
```

But on what object? You might think on **Kernel** or **Object**, but that doesn't actually work.

As an example, given this module:

```
module MyMethod
  def self.mymethod
    Dir.chdir('/tmp') do
      `ls`
    end
  end
end
```

I could write a test like this:

```
class MyMethodTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_my_method
    mock_block = mock
    mock_directory_contents = mock
    MyMethod.expects("`").with('ls').returns(mock_directory_contents)
    Dir.expects(:chdir).yields(mock_block).returns(mock_directory_contents)
    assert_equal mock_directory_contents, MyMethod.mymethod
  end
end
```

Part of the trick is to figure out which object to expect the *backtick* method to be invoked on. It depends on the context - whatever **self** is when that method is invoked. Here it is the module **MyMethod**, but depending on where you define **mymethod** it will be different.